Choosing between That and Who
Which one of the following sentences is more appropriate (from both grammatical and daily conversational points of view)?

I love things and people "who are beautiful.
I love things and people "that" are beautiful.
I love people and things "that" are beautiful.
I love the things "that" and the people "who" are beautiful.


Thanks so much for your excellent solution. I do agree with you that the question is a little bit weird. This was a question from a very nice friend, and I'm eager to find the best answer for him.

People that is more acceptable than things who, so (2) and (3) are the best options - but @user405662's version is the most idiomatic.

Google gives examples on social media like "Give up the things and people that hold you back" "The things and people that matter most to you may not be the things and people that matter most to others" "Align yourself with the things and people that make YOU feel good" (all "that" rather than "who"). But possibly other versions are preferred in edited writing.

There seem to be two issues wrapped into one here.  The point seems to be about which relative pronoun to use, and yet there is a second issue about how to take a sentence like this.  Could I not take sentence 1 to mean that the subject likes people (sc. unconditionally) and things that are beautiful?  So they like  people and  things that are beautiful.?

@Tuffy Yes, but the scope ambiguity associated with 'Z-like X and Y' has been addressed here before. Whatever, 405662 has the most sensible solution. I'd add that the 'beautifuls' here are subtly different, so using it before each of the two nouns is especially appropriate.

@Tuffy Possibly, although it appears you've read it backwards. "things" is unconditional, and "people" is qualified. But when that's intended, we usually use punctuation and additional wording to set it off: "I love things, and also people who are beautiful".

The pronoun "that" can be used for people, although it is more common and generally preferable to use "who" or "whom". You're most likely to see it used in connection with actions (eg "I like people that dance" or "there was a man that I would pass on my way to work"). When you are speaking about identifying things or characteristics of a person or their individual abilities, traits etc, it doesn't feel natural to use "that" - I would expect a native speaker to say, for example, "I like a man who can dance" or "there was a man to whom I would speak to on my way to work".
When you are using a single phrase or word to join different, possibly unrelated ideas, you have to be aware that things could sound unusual together. For example, if you listed things you liked and said "I like female singers like Adele, Beyonce, and dogs" you'd be grammatically correct but it would sound like 'dogs' is part of your list of female singers. So, despite passing a grammar check, you'd phrase it differently. Likewise, perhaps you shouldn't presume that English can accommodate you wanting to talk about people and inanimate objects in the same sentence using just one pronoun.

Interesting. I like a man who can dance sounds entirely natural to me. Is this a case of regional or dialectic differences?

@PeterKirkpatrick sorry I may not have phrased that well - that is an example of how it should be phrased, so we agree
